# MVC half complex Model Bound other half always null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

**UPDATE!**

Okay I have now tested creating two actionresults based on what form you are sending.

One of the views are always correctlybound the login model. The other is not bound always returns null.

Model is structured like this

```
public class RegisterAndLogin
{
    public LogOnModel Login { get; set; }
    public interested_users Register { get; set; }
}

//This model never any values after HTTP post
public class interested_users
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "UserType")]
    public string UserType { get; set; }    
    [Display(Name = "Date Inserted")]
    public DateTime DateInserted { get; set; }   
    [Display(Name = "IP")]
    public string IpAdress { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> SelectItems { get; set; }
}
```

And the view

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.ViewModel.RegisterAndLogin

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Start by filling in your email";
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">       </script>
```

```
<h2 class="title">Sign up!</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Home", FormMethod.Post))
{   

 <div class="form-item">
         @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Register.Email,null,"emailbox",null)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Register.Email)
    </div>
 <div class="form-item">
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Register.UserType,Model.Register.SelectItems, new { @class = "emailbox" })
    </div>
 <input type="submit" name="Register"  value="Register" class="form-submit" />
 }
```

**UPDATED!**

I load two partial views in my main view.

On of them is the one above and the other is the partial login view.

Somethings fishy.. If i tell the NOT WORKING view to 
@using (Html.BeginForm())

It does not go back to the ActionReslut without HTTP, it goes to the HTTP again.. Which tells me the other form (login form) is doing something I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Register.Email,"emailbox")
```

Comment: Does not work.. I think it's because I have two different forms. Where it seems the last form(loginform) that is working is doing something fishy which in turn destroys everything for the other field, see updated question part.